# Установка панели управления на VPS

Tags: веб-программирование, vps, ispmanager

ДД!
Был куплен VPS с базовыми настройками.Так как хостинг предлагал перенести сайты бесплатно, решили не париться и понадеяться на них. итог менеджер не установлен. А на сервере 3 сайта в размере около 6-7 гб. Вопрос следующий: можно ли установить менеджер не на пустой сервер? и как если это возможно. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Установить то можно, только надо знать какую панель, какой менеджер и куда устанавливать. Если вы про ispmanager говорите, то его сперва купить надо.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.